# Get previous object item in javascript

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I have an object with keys and data. From a key I want to get the previous item.

I've seen similar topics before but the solutions are really complicated.

*I also added a function that does not work but how I wish it would work*

**Simplified code**

```js
let obj = {
  slug:        'my-page',
  title:       'My title',
  description: 'My description',
  content:     'My content'
};

let previous = obj.previousItem('description'); // Does not work

console.log(previous);
```

**Expected result**

> { title: 'My title'
>   }

- ES5 or even ES6 is fine
- I prefer a simple solution to a complicated one, maybe without loops

Comment: You should use an array if you rely on the order.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does ES6 introduce a well-defined order of enumeration for object properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30076219/does-es6-introduce-a-well-defined-order-of-enumeration-for-object-properties)

Comment: @str Why is that? Will the order be lost?

Comment: It might be. See the duplicate question for more information.

Comment: Generally speaking, object properties are *unordered*.

Comment: Although most browsers have a fixed iteration order these days, the order of properties is NOT guaranteed by the specification for all JS versions before the newest ones. So if you have to be 100% sure about an order of something, use an array. And in this case, it';s rather simple. A basic 'pagination' wrapper where you save the current index and have `.prev()` and `.next()` subtract/add to the index and return. A more complex version can be made with iterators.

Comment: An alternative to the array is a Map, which will preserve the insert order. But overall, there is plenty of [dupes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order) for this.

Comment: After some research I think map is the way to go `let map = new Map(Object.entries(obj));` just like VLAZ said.

Comment: @JensTörnell Not really. The property order of  `Object.entries` is *not* specified. Using it to create a `Map` won't change that. Either use a `Map` exclusively (i.e. no plain object) or use something like `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` to create the `Map`.

Answer (score -3):

**Object used to be to have no order**, but actually they have and I would not rely on this order.

But anyway, you could filter by the next key/value pair and get an object.

```js
let obj = { slug: 'my-page', title: 'My title', description: 'My description', content: 'My content' },
    previous = Object.fromEntries(Object
        .entries(obj)
        .filter((_, i, { [i + 1]: next = [] }) => next[0] === 'description')
    );

console.log(previous);
```

Comment: While this will work as intended, object property order is not guaranteed and thus, this is a bad idea in general. Quote from object definition: `4.3.3 Object
An object is a member of the type Object. It is an unordered collection of properties each of which contains a primitive value, object, or function.` However, ES6 `Map` is similar and *will* guarantee the order. So i recommend using that instead

Comment: i know this, assuming op know this, too.

Answer (score -3):

I think somethink like this

```
Object.prototype.previousItem = function(propName) {
  const arr = Object.keys(this);
  let indx = arr.indexOf(propName)-1;
  if (indx<0) return null;
  const result = {};
  result[arr[indx]] = this[arr[indx]];
  return result;
}
```

Comment: It would be better to use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`. ES6 requires this to maintain order, `Object.keys` isn't required.

Comment: Not sure. The ordering of the enumerable properties in the array is consistent with the ordering exposed by a for...in loop (or by Object.keys()) over the properties of the object.

Comment: [Why is extending native objects a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice)

Comment: yes, but i want just run Jens code, not create the best app. In any case this is very strange desire

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30076219/does-es6-introduce-a-well-defined-order-of-enumeration-for-object-properties. It says that ES6 doesn't require ordering for `for-in` or `Object.keys()`, but it does require ordering for a number of other Object methods.

Comment: So they're consistent with each other, but not required to be the same as the order that the properties were created.

Comment: I think if we inject previousItem  to object, after we can on first call keep keys in array and after re-use it for next calls. So in this case we will have only 1 call for Object.keys and order is not impotent .

Answer (score -3):

```js
Object.prototype.previousItem = function(propName) {
  const arr = Object.keys(this);
  let indx = arr.indexOf(propName)-1;
  if (indx<0) return null;
  const result = Object.create(null); // just clear output
  result[arr[indx]] = this[arr[indx]];
  return result;
}

let obj = {
  slug:        'my-page',
  title:       'My title',
  description: 'My description',
  content:     'My content'
};

let previous = obj.previousItem('description'); //  work

console.log(previous);
```

Answer (score -3):

You can try following to get the previous item

```
let object = {
    slug: 'my-page',
    title: 'My title',
    description: 'My description',
    content: 'My content'
}
let previous = previousItem(object, 'description');
console.log(previous);


function previousItem(object, str) {
    let lastKey = "";

    for (const key in object) {
        if (object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            if (key == str){
                lastKey = lastKey || key;
                let obj = { };
                obj[lastKey] = object[lastKey];
                return obj;
            } else {
                lastKey = key;
            }
        }
    }
}
```